# How to set the stream content in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, dompdf

I'm using PHP and PHPExcel to get the image filename from a database and perform the stream reader operation. I set my image by using the `setImageResource` function but it isn't working as expected. Here's my code:

```
<?php
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once '../classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

    if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
        die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

    $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
    $rendererLibrary = 'dompdf.php';
    $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../libs/classes/dompdf/';

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Tes');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Image...');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
    $img = imagecreatefrompng('C:/Users/Downloads/logo.png');
    $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
    $objDrawing->setName('Test image');
    $objDrawing->setDescription('Test image');
    $objDrawing->setImageResource($img);
    $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_PNG);
    $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
    $objDrawing->setHeight(150);
    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A4');
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());



    if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath)) {
        die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
        );
    } 

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
    $objWriter->save('test.pdf');
    exit;
```

Comment: can you give some code, that you've tried so far ?

Comment: $file = fopen('logo.png', 'r'); $img = stream_get_contents($file); header("content-type: image/png"); $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing(); $objDrawing->setName('logo'); $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1'); $objDrawing->setImageResource($img); $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_PN‌​G); $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);$ob‌​jDrawing->setHeight(36); $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

Comment: Please provide that to your question. :)

Comment: This code only i have used to trying to set the stream content.

Comment: You can try use `$data = file_get_contents("logo.png");` instead using `$file and $img` in `fopen`, to get the image content.

Comment: if i use like this mean where i want to specifies the read mode for logo.png file

Comment: Please check my answer. I don't try it first, but I hope it'll run well. You can try it. :)

Comment: I have tried as you said. Its not working.

Comment: How does it work, and what did you expect instead? BTW: THis became an audit and is now featured on meta http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291502/is-this-another-good-review-audit-question

Answer (score 4):

Okey, First thing first `PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing()` can't solve your problem if you insist to use stream content and pass that to your worksheet your PDF will not render your image. But you can use `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing()' if you want to render your image too. You can trick it like this :

1. You can retrieve your image file from `stream_get_contents` or `file_get_contents`
2. and then you recreate it to the file.
3. The last you pass your image file path to the `$objDrawing->setPath($path_to_your_image);`

So, if you want to render your image too to the worksheet you must use `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing()` and for that you must point to your file path to render that image.

I assume this an Issue to the `PHPExcel` working with `DomPDF`. So, save a little discuss here and edit your `objDrawing` to this :

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setPath('logo.png');
```

For Complete sample I've made, Try this :

```
include 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");


$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf.php';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__). '/dompdf';


$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Tes');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B1', 'Image...');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getColumnDimension('A')
->setWidth(50);

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getRowDimension('2')
->setRowHeight(200);

// $img = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');
$data = file_get_contents("logo.png");
// $img = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$fp = fopen("logo1.png","w");
fwrite($fp,$data);
fclose($fp);

$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
$objDrawing->setPath('logo1.png');

// $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Test image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Test image');
// $objDrawing->setImageResource($img);
// $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_PNG);
// $objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_DEFAULT);
// $objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A2');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath)) {
    die(
        'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
        '<br />' .
        'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure'
    );
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->save('test.pdf');

echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
```

Glad to help you, Hope this will help you out :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75821/discussion-on-answer-by-eko-junaidi-salam-how-to-set-the-stream-content-in-phpex).